# Linking DOM elements with GWT

Tags: gwt

Im a relative newcomer to GWT.

Im working on a GWT application, where I have a lot of table data that is to be displayed on a page and a redirect to a different service which happens when I click on each cell's data. Currently what is happening is that the entire HTML(with all of the cells' hyperlinks) is being created on the server side and returned as a big string which is rendered on the client side. As you can imagine, it doesnt scale well. I need to make this redirect more dynamic. Can anyone suggest how I could link the DOM elements with  GWT code to make this happen?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In GWT there is **[Ui Binder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder)**

Declare your all ui on client side and  hit the server only for the `valuable` `data`.

> Browsers are better at building DOM structures by cramming big strings of HTML into innerHTML attributes than by a bunch of API calls. UiBinder naturally takes advantage of this, and the result is that the most pleasant way to build your app is also the best way to build it.

So avoid passing html through the **wire**.